# Java Iterate internal information in value of a Map <Key>

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, loops, dictionary

Please I'm doing a practice with MongoDB and Spring but I have the following dilemma; in the DB I have the following information:

```
[
  {
 "menu":"querys",
 "optionsList":[
 {
    "options":[
       "0001",
       "0022",
       "0014",
       "0041",
       "0042",
       "0043"
     ]
   }
 ]
},{..},{...}
]
```

The structure of the object in Java is as follows:

```
@Document(collection = "menu")
public class GetAllRules implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 7375796948388333325L;

@JsonProperty(value = "menu")
private String name;

@JsonProperty(value = "optionsList")
private List<Map<String, ?>> optionsList;

//Getters and Setters.
```

With the following method I get the JSON (I'm using the MongoRepository), with the first FOR I get all the information and with the second I get the inner map, but I don't know how to iterate the information found inside **options**, I would appreciate it if someone can you help me with the issue:

```
@GetMapping("/final")
public String obtener() {

List<GetAllRules> allRules = iGetMenuService.getAll(); // Mongo List

String key= "options";

for (GetAllRules rules : allRules) {
    for (Map<String, ?> internal : rules.getOptionsList()) {
        System.out.println(internal.get(key));
        }

    }

return "finalizado";
}
```

With line **System.out.println(internal.get(key));** I get the key values ​​that I need but now I don't know how to go through it one by one to do something specific with each data.

```
[0001, 0022, 0014, 0041, 0042, 0043]
[0238]
[1001, 1003]
[0108, 0109, 0102]
[0601, 0602, 0604, 0604]
[0603, 0901, 0901]
[0238]
[0001]
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"...but now I don't know how to go through it one by one to do something specific with each data."_ Please tell what is it you want to do with each data?

Comment: Hello prasad_, the idea is that with each value that I retrieve, I go to a list that is in a JSON and retrieve some information in order to create another object and return it, it is like crossing two JSONs for that value and building a third object with the information What I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how to iterate the information found inside **options**

Your **options** field is just another array/list of strings, so you can specify that in your pojo:

```
@JsonProperty(value = "optionsList")
private List<Map<String, List<String>>> optionsList;
```

with that, you can add one more iteration

```
        for (GetAllRules rules : allRules) {
            for (Map<String, List<String>> internal : rules.getOptionsList()) {
                for (String value : internal.get(key)) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                    // will print "0001", ...
                }
            }
        }
```

Nicer way to handle this would be to use Java streams - you don't want to use too many nested loops,
it may look like this:

```
        allRules.stream()
                .map(GetAllRules::getOptionsList)
                .flatMap(Collection::stream)
                .flatMap(option -> option.get(key).stream())
                .forEach(System.out::println);
```

Comment: mehowthe, Thank you very much for the answer, it helped me to understand the problem, could you please tell me how it would be with Java Stream.

Comment: You are welcome, Example attached to the answer

Comment: mehowthe, I try to apply the lambda stream but optionList tells me that it doesn't have any getOptionsList(), I understand that with the expression the FOR cycles are removed and the complexity of nested cycles is avoided

Comment: Sorry - I was using slightly different object structure for this example, it is now adjusted to your objects (I hope so)